# Change my applications's exe file version in VB6

Tags: vb6

i made an application in vb6 now i have given it a product version from project/properties but i noticed the win explorer has two tags for exe a product version and a file version.

i want to edit the file version of my app's exe any idea how can i do that? file version should be x.x.x.x

i wanted to to change the file verision not the product version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Resource Hacker and accomplish this easily,

Download from [here](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Comment: +1 on resource hacker. I wrote a blog post about doing this very thing a while back.

http://www.darinhiggins.com/?s=VB+and+resource+files

Resource hacker is also available direct from Angus's site

http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 8):

VB6 automatically sets the *File version* equal to the *Product version*.
You specify these through the [project properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263317(v=VS.60).aspx) dialog, Make tab, Major Minor and Revision.

- *Product version* always has three parts: Major.Minor.Revision
- *File version* always has four parts: Major.Minor.0.Revision. Microsoft decided to put an extra zero between Minor and Revision.

Comment: gr8 answer Mark but what if you need file version to be 5.6.7.2 and product version to be 5.6.2 what vb does is 5.6.0.2

Comment: @jaminator If you really, truly, must have those numbers then use resource hacker like [Dr TJ says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021311/change-my-applicationss-exe-file-version-in-vb6/4022086#4022086). But is it really worth the hassle? These numbers are really intended so that install programs etc. can tell the difference between different versions of your program. You can use something else for your "branding" marketing version identifier for the users: *MegaApp 2010* or *MegaApp Moccaccino*

Answer (score 0):

From (distant) memory this can be set by looking at the project options dialog. You can place a * into the boxes if you want the version to auto-increment.

Comment: MrTelly, there is checkbox option AutoIncrement there, but i wanted to to change the file verision not the product version.