# Can I modify the internal version of an exe

Tags: vb.net, vb6, versioning

I have several VB6 exe's/dll's that I have created, when I right click on the file and get the properties it says:

- `File version` - `4.2.0.9`
- `Product Version` - `4.02.0009`

Is it possible to change the `File Version`? I want this to say `4.2.9.123`

I want to change this programmatically, so where is the file would I find these values? Are they at a specific location?

Is this going to cause an issue registering the exe/dll's with COM if I change the internal version?

(If anyone has a code solution, my language of choice is VB.NET)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021311/change-my-applicationss-exe-file-version-in-vb6

Comment: @KAJ It was a duplicate when you posted that comment, but Matt has now clarified he needs to do this programmatically, so it's no longer a duplicate! :)

Comment: Why can't you just rebuild the binaries with the updated versions? I'm curious as to what scenario you are running into.

Comment: @SpectralGhost - because they are VB6 binaries and it only supports three version numbers: `Major.Minor.Revision` but the `FileVersion` standard is four numbers so MS decided to insert a 0: `Major.Minor.0.Revision`

Comment: That makes sense. I never noticed that until you pointed that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use Win32 API calls to do this - specifically the [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to modify the [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) resource.

Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6317/Updating-version-information-at-run-time and [Replace Version Info Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395570/replace-version-info-resource) for more details.

You can probably use P/Invoke but it may be simpler to just go with C++.

Answer (score 0):

You need a resource editor like this [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/)
You will find the FileVersion inside the VersionInfo resource.
Changing the FileVersion info should have no side effect for COM
However better have a backup first.......

Comment: Thanks Steve - I am after a programmatic solution though - maybe that was not clear - I will edit my question